# Ability or method to change interface in Java based off reference

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What I want to be able to do is the following:
Lets say I have some interface called Communication

I then have a package called Core that wants to use the Communication interface.

Then I have 2 packages for communication one for serial and one for MQ with interfaces in each:
-ISerialCommunication extends Communication
-IRabbitMQCommunication extends Communication

Is there a way or methodology for me to automatically use ISerialCommunication by having that package referenced in the build path and not the RabbitMQ package (basically a plug and play package based off what my client wants), besides creating my own interface factory based off of configurations?

Im just curious if there are any libraries or design principles I am missing here.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You have an interface `Communication` then your classes `ISerialCommunication` & `IRabbitMQCommunication` implementing your interface.

If I understand fine you want to make your code loosely coupled.

You can write your code this way

```
Communication comm = new ISerialCommunication();
Communication comm = new IRabbitMQCommunication();
```

use the comm reference in your code so at runtime you just change the implementation either ISerial or IRabbit. Choose either of the two. The reference `comm` will remain the same, you don't have to change the reference at other places in your code.